# How do daemons work?

Tags: users, daemon

If a user wants to execute a command, he has to first log in into a system. But some users in the system have `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` set as a default shell in the `/etc/password` file. If I change `/bin/bash` to `/bin/false` in case of my user, I won't be able to log in into the system, so I also won't be able to run commands.

But the shellless users do it anyway:

```
# ps -eo "%mem,user,group,args" | grep -i dns
 0.0 dnscrypt dnscrypt /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --user dnscrypt --local-address=127.0.0.1:53 --resolver-address=208.67.222.222:443 --provider-name=2.dnscrypt-cert.opendns.com --provider-key=B735:1140:206F:225D:3E2B:D822:D7FD:691E:A1C3:3CC8:D666:8D0C:BE04:BFAB:CA43:FB79

# cat /etc/passwd | grep -i dns
dnscrypt:x:113:121::/home/dnscrypt:/bin/false
```

How can a user without a shell execute a command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In POSIX, every running process has three User IDs (UIDs) associated with it; the *real UID*, which identifies the user who launched the process, the *effective UID*, which is used to determine what resources the process can access, and the *saved Set-User-ID* (SUID), which is the effective UID the process had when it started (at the point of the last `exec()` call). Of these, the effective UID is the most significant, since it is the one used when determining access control decisions regarding the process.

Daemons are typically started from init scripts, which are executed by the init system, running with root privileges. Processes may change the real/effective UID via the [`setuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setuid.html), [`seteuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/seteuid.html) and [`setreuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setreuid.html) system calls. This is the case with the `dnscrypt-proxy` invocation given as an example<sup>1</sup> in the question. The `--user dnscrypt` option tells `dnscrypt-proxy` to assume the identity of the user `dnscrypt`. A privileged process may assume the identity of any user (even changing its saved SUID), whereas unprivileged user processes may only set the effective UID to the real user ID, the effective UID or the saved set-user ID.

The basic uses cases for changing the UIDs is for a privileged process to drop its privileges, either permanently, or temporary. The latter case is needed by programs with the [SUID bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) set, which need to perform some unprivileged operations using their real UID, then regain their SUID granted privileges. The POSIX.1-1990 standard adopted the traditional System V behaviour for the `setuid()` function, which specifies `setuid()` to behave differently for privileged and unprivileged users. When the caller had the appropriate privilege, the function set the calling process' real UID, effective UID, and saved SUID. When the caller did not have the appropriate privilege, the function set only the effective UID, as described above.

In contrast, 4.3BSD did not support the saved SUID, but handles the latter case with separate functions. While `setuid()` always set both the real and effective UIDs, `seteuid()` could be used to set only the effective UID (like `setuid()` in POSIX1-1990 for non-privileged users). Lastly, `setreuid()` allowed processes to swap their real and effective UIDs, in order to support previously-privileged processes to regain their privileges.

The POSIX:2001 standard introduced a mandatory feature named _POSIX_SAVED_IDS. This allows a SUID application to switch its effective UID back and forth between the values of its saved SUID and effective user ID. More information can be found in the rationale section of the [POSIX:2004 specification for `setuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setuid.html). In Linux, [`setuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) is implemented like the POSIX version with  the _POSIX_SAVED_IDS  feature.

<sup>1: [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) can be made to display the real UID, effective UID and saved SUID with the `ruser`, `euser` and `suser` format specifiers, e.g `ps -eo "ruser,euser,suser,args"`.</sup>

Comment: If understood you well, the real UID is root, the saved UID is dnscrypt-proxy. But I don't get the effective UID. What would that be? Could you write a little bit more about the third UID?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov: _"If understood you well, the real UID is root, the saved UID is dnscrypt-proxy."_ **No**, while initially, both the real and effective UIDs (and therefore also the saved SUID) are 0 (root), unless `dnscrypt-proxy` is a SUID binary, when a privileged process calls `setuid()`, all three associated UIDs are changed, in this case to `dnscrypt`.  The effective UID is the most important one, as it is the one which affects the access control decisions made by the kernel. I updated the answer with additional information.

Comment: this answer should be turn into a wiki answer

Comment: because in my opinion it's usefull and complete and people should be able to complete that as it's not a problem a resolution but a common knowledge on Unix linux system. but that my only opinion, I ay misunderstand the point of a wiki post

Comment: @Kiwy Thanks. I'll consider it, but I also think that when writing an answer, it is as important to consider what information to leave out as it is to consider what information to put it. I wouldn't want the answer to grow out of proportion either. Feel free to suggest edits if you think something important has been left out, you (and other) can still do that even thought it's not a wiki post.